# Orden de Post(ida y vuelta al BackEnd) desde angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, backend

Estoy intentando insertar en una Base de datos secciones, a toda la inserción la manejo con C# en controladores(Mi proyecto es una WebApi). Lo que quiero es que haga una inserción en cada ciclo de los for. Pero al controlador va solo una vez, y es cuando se termina de correr todo el angular(No se si me explico bien) Esto lo quiero hacer así porque quiero que con un solo botón me guarde todas las secciones. (No por cada sección que quiero crear que exista un botón y que de ahí vaya al controlador)

Mi codigo en angularJs es:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.ListaTempProductos.length; i++) {
        var Seccion = new Object();
        var idUlt = $scope.SeccionUltima;
        var idSeccionObtenida = idUlt[0]['idSeccion'];
        DetalleSeccion.idSeccion = idSeccionObtenida;
        DetalleSeccion.idProducto = $scope.ListaTempProductos[i]['idProducto'];
        CrearDetalleSeccion(JSON.stringify(DetalleSeccion));

    }
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.ListaTempPlatos.length; i++) {
        var Seccion = new Object();
        var idUlt = $scope.SeccionUltima;
        var idSeccionObtenida = idUlt[0]['idSeccion'];
        DetalleSeccion.idSeccion = idSeccionObtenida;
        DetalleSeccion.idPlato = $scope.ListaTempPlatos[i]['idPlato'];
        CrearDetalleSeccion(JSON.stringify(DetalleSeccion));

    }

   function CrearDetalleSeccion(detalle) {
    //Crea detalle tercero
    var idDetalle = $http.post('/api/DetalleSeccion/PostDetalleSeccion', detalle).then(function (response) {
        alert("guardado");

    });


}
```

Mi html es:

```
 <form class="form-inline" id="formSeccionDetalle" style="margin:10px; visibility:hidden; background-color:azure;">

        <div class="form-group" style="margin:10px;">
            <label for="nombre">Seleccione los productos que iran en esta sección:</label>
            <div>
                <select class="form-control" id="listaProductosParaDetalle">
                    <option ng-repeat="dto in productos"> {{dto.nombreProducto}} </option>

                </select>

            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-toolbar btn-circle" id="AgregarProducto"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin:10px;">
            <label for="nombre">Seleccione los platos que iran en esta sección:</label>
            <div>
                <select class="form-control" id="listaPlatosParaDetalle">
                    <option ng-repeat="dto in platos"> {{dto.nombrePlato}} </option>

                </select>

            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-toolbar btn-circle" id="AgregarPlato"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="margin:10px;">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="x in ListaTempProductos">
                        {{ x.nombreProducto }}
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="btnBorrar" ng-click="EliminarProducto($index)">
                            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="x in ListaTempPlatos">
                        {{ x.nombrePlato }}
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="btnBorrar" ng-click="EliminarPlato($index)">
                            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <button class="btn btn-danger" id="guardarTodo">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>



    </form>
```

Alguien me podría explicar de manera resumida como es que puedo alterar el orden de esto?

Comment: No entendi, quiere que vaya solo una vez con el listado completo o que vaya cada iteracion?

Comment: quiero que en cada iteracion del for vaya al controlador y me inserte una seccion(tomando en cada ciclo un idProducto o IdPlato de la lista temporal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo te diría que mejor hicieras una solo llamada desde el front con un body tipo array con las diferentes secciones.

Prepararía el backend para aceptar un array en el body y desde el backend haría el Bulk para hacer las diferentes inserciones a la base de datos. Con eso te evitas hacer tantas peticiones http desde el cliente y saturarás menos al server. Además, en dispositivos móviles o con una conexión lenta siempre es mejor hacer menos llamadas.

Sería algo así:

```
var idDetalle = $http({
   mehotd: 'POST',
   url: '/api/DetalleSeccion/PostDetalleSeccion',
   data: {
     bulk: [
       { id: '2' type: "producto", data: { detalle: "detalle de la sección", otroCampo: "Lo que sea..." } },
       { id: '4' type: "producto", data: { detalle: "detalle de la sección", otroCampo: "Lo que sea..." } }
       { id: '16' type: "plato", data: { /* los datos que queremos almacenar */ } }
     ]
   }
}, detalle).then(function (response) {
    alert("guardado");

});
```

Luego en el back, recorre el array `bulk` del *body* y realiza allí las inserciones a la BD.

Además, dependiendo del tipo de base de datos que utilices al realizar el bulk desde el backend, se puede hacer de **forma atómica** (lo cual significa que si una falla, fallan todas) pudiendo dar al cliente el mensaje de que no se ha guardado y no tener las diferentes filas des-actualizadas (unas si se hayan guardado y otras no). Eso, depende de los casos, es recomendable o incluso necesario (en tu caso lo desconozco).

Es solo una recomendación desde mi humilde punto de vista. Se que requiere más desarrollo pero **tener una buena api o un buen backend**, luego te facilitara muchas tareas en el front.

Comment: Muchas gracias !!!!! Realmente lo que me dijiste era la respuesta que necesitaba. Desconocía el bulk.. voy a intentar con eso y veo que sale :) Genio!!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido. Si surgen más dudas ya sabes! ;)